# Randomized 2D Array

Tags: arrays

I am trying to randomize a 2D `array[3][3]` with values from `1-9` using `rand()` and then parse the int to chars to place in the array.

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void showgame();
void player();
bool gameover();

char player1, player2;
char user;
bool tie = false;
const int ROW = 3;
const int COL = 3;
int bboard[ROW][COL];

char aboard[3][3]= {{'1', '2', '3'},
                   {'4', '5', '6'},
                   {'7', '8', '9'}};

 int main()
 {

 unsigned seed = time(0);
 srand(seed);

for(int i=0; i<ROW; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<COL; j++)
        bboard[i][j] = char (rand() %  i*COL+j+1);
```

The result will be a hard coded tictactoe board and a randomized board. When the (`aboard`) cell is selected `1-9` the `X` or `O` will be placed in a randomized cell on (bboard) givng you an additional chance at winning. I have tried various methods of doing this but none have compiled. This method compiles and however I get an error I have not encountered before nor can I find the problem. I have tried moving the declarations of `ROW`, `COL` and `bboard` into the `main` but still am unable to get a compile. The program will run with `2` hard coded `2D` arrays outside of the `main` however `rand()` requires it be within the `main`?

JGrasp compiles however when I run the code the following error occurs:

```
----jGRASP wedge: process died on signal 8.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `rand() %  i*COL` part in line `bboard[i][j] = char (rand() %  i*COL+j+1);` this generates scenario of `divide-by-zero` error.
You can see [here](https://ideone.com/KbSPAV) that number generated are following:

```
0
0
0
3
3
3
6
6
6
```

To correct you can change the part `(rand() %  i*COL+j+1);` with `(rand() %  (i*COL+j+1));` **OR** `(rand() %  (i*COL+1)+j+1);` (whichever suits your need better) in the line `bboard[i][j] = char (rand() %  i*COL+j+1);`.